# AppEngine: Transient error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I get the exception below for more than three hours. Does anybody know how to get rid of it?

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transient error, please try again.
Error Code: 1
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)

Answer (score 0):

There was a service disruption today: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-sql-discuss/KHZzpRxkSj0/27ccmG9q34oJ

Are you still experiencing this problem?